# Sending and Receiving arrays via Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Is it possible to send an array through UDP Sockets using Python? I am using Python 2.5 and trying to send a simple array but it's not working. It can send the array successfully but when I try to print it with an item of the array the program crashes. I'm not sure what the error is as I take the precaution of converting the data into an array but it's not working. Hope I explained the problem as clearly as possible. I would appreciate the help!

```
# Client program

from socket import *
import numpy
from array import*

# Set the socket parameters
host = "localhost"
port = 21567
buf = 4096
addr = (host,port)

# Create socket
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)

def_msg = "===Enter message to send to server===";
print "\n",def_msg
a = array('i',[1,3,2])
# Send messages
while (1):
    data = raw_input('yes or now')
    if data!= "yes":
        break
    else:
        if(UDPSock.sendto(a,addr)):
            print "Sending message"

# Close socket
UDPSock.close()



# Server program

from socket import *

# Set the socket parameters
host = "localhost"
port = 21567
buf = 4096
addr = (host,port)

# Create socket and bind to address
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)

# Receive messages
while 1:
    data,addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    L = eval(data)
    if not data:
        print "Client has exited!"
        break
    else:
        print "\nReceived message '", L[1],"'"

# Close socket
UDPSock.close()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`eval` is doing something completely different than what you think.

To send data over network, you need to *serialize* it into an array of bytes, then *deserialize* it back. In Python, serialization of most objects can be done via `pickle` module:

```
if (UDPSock.sendto( pickle.dumps(a), addr)):
```

Deserialization:

```
data,addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
L = pickle.loads(data)
print repr(L) # prints array('i', [1, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 6):

I would personally use [`tostring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) and `fromstring` since the built-in serialization methods are [many times faster](http://thsant.blogspot.com/2007/11/saving-numpy-arrays-which-is-fastest.html) and pickle [may not support](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t698155-numpy-nan-not-surviving-pickle-unpickle.html) NaN, Inf and other undefined values.

Comment: `pickle` is terrible for sending numpy arrays, absolutely terrible. Picke is platform dependent, it's extremely inefficient for sending numpy arrays and numpy comes with really good serialization support in the module like `tostring` and `fromstring` but these are copy methods.  The best solutions I have implemented have been using Cython.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to send a python object through a socket, it is normal that it doesn't work, you can't send objects in a socket, objects are not data, they are the representation of some data in a given programming language. You need to "translate" your object to data and re-create the object from the data on the other socket's side. One way to do this would be with the `pickle` module.

On the client side, you "pickle" the object:

```
data = pickle.dumps(my_array)
```

And on the server side, you "unpickle" the received data:

```
my_array = pickle.loads(received_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to `pickle` the array. Pickle is a python library to en- and decode python objects. It is able to do much more, but it is definitely sufficient to fulfill your task:

on the sender side you `pickle` the object to a string:

```
pickled_string = pickle.dumps(a)
```

on the receiver side you `unpickle` the object:

```
a = pickle.loads(received_string)
# a is now your sent array
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since this question was asked, but I thought it's worth sharing the [`jsonsocket` library](https://github.com/mdebbar/jsonsocket). It makes it really easy to send strings, lists and dictionaries over sockets. It can handle big amounts of data efficiently. And you don't need to do any manual serialization/deserialization. Under the hood, it serializes the data as JSON strings on the client, and deserializes it on the server.

Comment: It is a very good library. It saved me a lot of time and brain efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need UDP specifically, try zmqObjectExchanger (https://github.com/ZdenekM/zmq_object_exchanger). It wraps pickle and zmq to transfer python objects over TCP.