# How can I pack numpy bool arrays into a string of bits?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

## Overview

In numpy, I have an array of bools. The array was retrieved from an image; it is two-dimensional and  contains 1024 columns and 768 rows. I want to push this data over an Ethernet cable. There are multiple ways to do this, but for my purposes speed is extremely crucial, and therefore memory is also very crucial.

Since there are `1024 x 768 = 786432` elements (pixels) in each array, and each element is either `True` or `False`, it is theoretically possible to pack the array into 98,304 uncompressed bytes or 96 kilobytes.

```
786432 bits / 8 bits per byte =         98304 bytes
98304 bytes / 1024 bytes per kilobyte = 96    kilobytes
```

This requires flattening the array

```
[ [True, False, True, ..., True]
  [False, True, True, ..., True]
  ...
  [True, True, False, ..., False] ]

# flatten the array

[True, False, True, ..., False]
```

Which can theoretically be represented as bits of bytes, since 786,432 bits fits evenly into 98,304 bytes; each array should be able to be represented by 98,304 eight-bit chars.

## The Question

How can I quickly send 1024-by-768 `bool` numpy arrays over Ethernet? I'm looking into the `bitstring` python library, but I'm not sure how to quickly pipe the numpy arrays into a `bitstring` class.

## Additional Information / Questions

To be specific, I'm sending these arrays from a Raspberry Pi 2 to a regular Raspberry Pi.

1. Is `socket` and `SOCK_STREAM` the fastest way to go about this?
2. Given the RPis computing power, would it be faster to compress and decompress the arrays? If so, the **compression must be lossless.**
3. I've looked into serializing the numpy arrays rather than using `bitstring` stuff, but the pickled objects are too large to send over `SOCK_STREAM`. Am I doing something wrong with `socket` stuff?

## My Code / Solution [SOLVED]

### Client

```
import socket
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 7071
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

image = imread('input.png')[:,:,[2]]
image[image < 170] = 0
image[image != 0] = 1
image = numpy.reshape(image, (-1, 1))
image = numpy.packbits(image)
data = image.tostring()

sock.connect(ADDRESS)
for i in range(0, 93804, 1024):
    sock.send(data[i:i+1024])
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
sock.close()
```

### Server

```
import socket
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 7071
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(ADDRESS)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    c, addr = sock.accept()
    data = ''
    package = c.recv(1024)
    while package:
        data += package
        package = c.recv(1024)
    image = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    image = numpy.unpackbits(image)
    image = numpy.reshape(image, (-1, 768))
    imsave('output.png', image)
    c.close()
sock.close()
```

As you can see, I ended up each array over TCP/SOCK_STREAM via a series of 1024-byte packets.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`np.packbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) to pack the contents of an `np.bool` array into an `np.uint8` array 1/8th of the size, such that each 'packed' boolean element uses only a single bit. The original array can be recovered using [`np.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy.unpackbits).

```
import numpy as np

x = array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.bool)

print(x.itemsize, x.nbytes)
# (1, 16)

xp = np.packbits(x)
print(xp)
# [ 24 139]

print(xp.itemsize, xp.nbytes)
# (1, 2)

print(np.unpackbits(xp))
# [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
```

The most obvious way to go from here would be to serialize your packed array to a raw string of bytes, [pipe it through a UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7107075/1461210), then deserialize it and unpack it on the other side. numpy's native serialization ([`.tostring()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) and [`np.fromstring()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)) will probably be much faster than using `pickle` or `cPickle`.

If you want to play around with compression, one option would be to use the native [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) module to compress the string of bytes before passing it through the pipe, then decompress it on the other side. Whether you see any benefit from this will depend strongly on how compressible your input arrays are, as well as on the hardware that's doing the compression/decompression.

Comment: I originally followed this train of thought, but then I got caught up in UDP issues. My array is larger than the maximum theoretical size of any UDP packet. How can I such a large array elegantly (ideally I'd like to send it in one or two lines of Python code)? Do I have to break it up into smaller packets and use TCP/SOCK_STREAM, or can I somehow send a large number of bytes all at once?

Comment: @user3745189 that seems worthy of a new question.

Comment: @user3745189 I second Mark's comment. You're much more likely to get help with the networking part of your question if you post it separately with a more appropriate set of tags.